# SQL - does database extract repeating joined data multiple times or just once?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a performance question. In a query joining another table (the other acting as dictionary) where the joined data repeat, because foreign key value is repeated in many records of the base table, will database engine extract the repeating data multiple times (I mean by that not the presented output, but actually accessing and searching the table again and again), or is it smart enough to somehow cache the results and extract everything just once? I am using mySQL.

I mean a situation like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Tasks 
  JOIN People
    ON Tasks.personID = People.ID;
```

Lets assume People table consists of:

```
ID | Name
1  | John
2  | Mary
```

And Tasks:

```
ID | personID
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 2
```

Will "John" data be physically extracted twice or once? Is it worth trying to avoid such queries?

Comment: How the database executes queries is much, much less important than whether or not the query does what you need.  And on such small data, any difference in performance is likely to be unmeasurable.

Comment: I know that for small single queries it's not relevant, but this is just a simplified example. In reality I will join multiple dictionary tables. The query will do it's job, however I can try to solve this differently (by eg storing a subset of `people` in the app to act as "cached dictionary" and extract them separately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`John` will show up twice in the result set.

However, if I interpret your question right, this is not about the *resulting* result set, but more about how the data is internally read to produce this result set.

In this case you have a join between two tables. In a join between two tables there's a "driving table" that's read first, and then the "secondary table" that is accessed once per each row of the driving table.

Now:

- If MySQL chooses `Tasks` as the driving table, then the row `John` from the `People` will be accessed twice (because it will be in the secondary table).
- If MySQL chooses `People` as the driving table, then naturally the row `John` will be accessed only once.

So, which option will MySQL pick? Get the execution plan and you'll find out. The table that shows up first in the plan is the driving table; the other is the secondary table. Mind that the execution plan may change in the future without notice.

**Note**: *accessing* doesn't mean to perform physical I/O on the disk. Once the row is read, it becomes "hot" and it's usually cached for some time; any repeated access will probably end up reading from the cache and won't cause more physical I/O.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So the reality is more complex than I expected, but there's some caching involved after all.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that it repeats the data. The string values are not cached or reduced to one per distinct value.

In general, this isn't a problem because you would run queries that have small result sets by selecting a limited subset of data.

But if you don't limit the query, it would produce a large result set, potentially with strings repeated.

Comment: In the question I didn't mean repetitions of string results in the output, I meant repetitions of accessing the dictionary table to get "John" for personID = 1.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL takes the table task and add for every row a/some row(s)  from people that fits.

It has to gather every row, that belongs **one** row of the table tasks.

So it would grab for the second row woth the same id also the same data again.

this is usually not aproblem as you would put the colums in an INDEX and s it would find them quickly